# Where can I find the logs for R executable files?

Tags: r, rscript

I have a file in R that I open with Rscript ( R for front-end windows) and it doesn't work, even if on other laptop it works. The black screen open and close in 1 second and I can't see the error.
Is there a way to find the log or smth to see why doesn't work? The file is simple, just with 3 command for install packages.

Thank you,

Edit: Here is the code. I repeat, this worked on other laptop. For sure there is an error, but because the window is close so quick, I can't see where is the problem.

```
install.packages("exifr",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("dplyr",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("rlang",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("leaflet",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

PS: I have Strawberry installed.

edit 2: I still search for a solution. I got this message when I tried to run with Rscript:
[image]

Comment: Are you runnung Rscript via douible-click ?Have you tried running Rscript in the console? If something is printed to stderr it should be visible there.

Comment: Where in console? Yes, I running with double click.

Comment: Sorry for calling it console. In Windows it's apparently named Command Prompt. This lists 10 ways to open the command prompt in Windows 10, search for your Windows version: https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/ Calling Rscript on windows is explained here: http://datacornering.com/how-to-run-r-scripts-from-the-windows-command-line-cmd/

Answer (score 0):

I seems that it just opens command line console, runs the script and closes the console. This way you cannot see the output.

Simple solution (not suggested): open the script in text editor and add line `Sys.sleep(60)` to the end of the file which will keep the console open for extra minute.

Long-term solution: install RStudio and open the file there

Comment: It doesn't work. If I add `Sys.sleep(60)`in the begging just it stay for a minute and after it close and if I add in the end, it doesn't sleep. I know about RStudio and of course I use it. But this is a solution for somebody that doesn't use R/RStudio. But, I repeat. This files worked on other laptop. Idk where is the pb now.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, you have to add the line to the end of file (answer updated)

Comment: I added to the end but nothing changed.

Comment: That could just mean that the script produces no output. Are there any `print` statements? Could you add the content of the script to the original question?

Comment: I added the content of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can choose a filename for R to put either it's output or it's errors into. The function
´sink` is meant to define exactly that.

Try

```
help(sink)
```

in your console to read how to put `sink` into your script:

> sink diverts R output to a connection (and must be used again to finish such a diversion, see below!). If file is a character string, a file connection with that name will be established for the duration of the diversion. [...] Messages sent to stderr() (including those from message, warning and stop) can be diverted by sink(type = "message") (see below).
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> zz <- file("all.Rout", open = "wt")
> sink(zz)
> sink(zz, type = "message")
> ```

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(324)`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Smth is weird here. I have the same R version, the code is very simple but I can't understand why it doesn't work. I can see that there is an error but because the window is close so quick, I don't have time to make at least a ps.